# (TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType') hikari.lightbulb

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.command
@lightbulb.option('modifier','add or subtracts from the original roll', required=False)
@lightbulb.option('op','add or sub', required=False)
@lightbulb.option('sides', 'sides on the die')
@lightbulb.command('r', 'rolls a set of dice')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def roll(ctx):
    sides, op, mod = ctx.options.sides, ctx.options.op, ctx.options.modifier
    sides = sides.split("d")
    tDice = sides[0]
    tSides = sides[1]

    if mod == "": mod = "0"
    if op == "-":
        mod = int(mod)
        mod = 0 - mod
    else:
        mod = int(mod)
        op = "+"
    if tDice == "": tDice = "1"
    
    tDice,tSides = int(tDice),int(tSides)
    tRoll = [random.randint(1,tSides) for i in range(tDice)]
    tRoll1 = int(math.fsum(tRoll))
    total = tRoll1 + mod
    
    await ctx.respond(f"{total}")
```

I'm using hikari.lightbulb, and I honestly dont see a problem with my code, but i keep getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/toritoab01/GitHub/RPG->Haven/rpgHaven/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightbulb/app.py", line >973, in handle_messsage_create_for_prefix_commands
> await self.process_prefix_commands(context)
> File "/home/toritoab01/GitHub/RPG->Haven/rpgHaven/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightbulb/app.py", line >945, in process_prefix_commands
> await context.invoke()
> File "/home/toritoab01/GitHub/RPG->Haven/rpgHaven/lib/python3.9/site->packages/lightbulb/context/base.py", line 276, in invoke
> await self.command.invoke(self)
> File "/home/toritoab01/GitHub/RPG->Haven/rpgHaven/lib/python3.9/site->packages/lightbulb/commands/prefix.py", line 112, in invoke
> await self(context)
> File "/home/toritoab01/GitHub/RPG->Haven/rpgHaven/lib/python3.9/site->packages/lightbulb/commands/base.py", line 357, in **call**
> return await self.callback(context)
> File "/home/toritoab01/GitHub/RPG-Haven/main.py", line 46, in roll
> mod = int(mod)
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a >number, not 'NoneType'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/toritoab01/GitHub/RPG-Haven/rpgHaven/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightbulb/app.py", line 992, in handle_messsage_create_for_prefix_commands
raise new_exc
lightbulb.errors.CommandInvocationError: An error occurred during command 'r' invocation

in regards to my "mod" variable  Any advice?

Comment: Are you supposed to be using `ctx.options.mod` or rather `ctx.options.modifier`?

Comment: You have lots of calls to `int()` in the code. Which one is getting the error?

Comment: Python exceptions usually come with a source code line number. This is provided to let you know which part of your program caused the exception. You need to be able to track this line number down if you want to effectively troubleshoot your code.

Comment: It's going to be in the `else` as the other `int(mod)` wouldn't be invoked on a `None` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. So in Hikari Lightbulb if you want to make an option not required you type in required= False , but you also have to put in a default value otherwise it defaults to None so in my case it would look like this

```py
@plugin.command
@lightbulb.option('modifier','add or subtracts from the original roll', required=False, default=0)
@lightbulb.option('op','add or sub', required=False, default="+")
@lightbulb.option('sides', 'sides on the die')
@lightbulb.command('r', 'rolls a set of dice')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
```

and problem solved!